# Is `dotnet run` is no different from `npm start` when using Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

The `*.csproj` file generated by `dotnet new angular` from `Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0` [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#installation) seems to render these commands as identical: `dotnet run` and `npm start`.

Whenever, I intend to run the SPA *and* the ASP.NET Core backend from Visual Studio Code I need to launch (pressing F5). Running `dotnet run` [will not run both](https://github.com/BryanWilhite/Songhay.Blog/issues/18).

Is this situation by design? Should I not even bother using `dotnet run` in VS Code?

Comment: What part of the *.csproj indicates that the `dotnet run` and `npm start` commands are identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `dotnet run` and `npm start`, they are total different. `dotnet run` is used to launch `.Net Core` project, and `npm start` is used to launch `Angular` project.

For the reason that `Pressing F5` will launch both `Core` and `Angular` project is that, when launching from `VS Code`, the `Environemnt` is `Development`, and then `Startup.Configure` will run code below:

```
spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
```

`UseAngularCliServer` will call `StartAngularCliServerAsync` to lauch `Angular` project for you which is corresponding to run `npm start`.

If you want to lauch `Angular` and `Core` project from `dotnet run`, there are two options for you

- Run `SET ASPNETCORE_Environment=Development` from CommandLin in Windows OS and Run `export ASPNETCORE_Environment=Development` in Linux or MacOS
- Remove the `if (env.IsDevelopment())` in Startup.

  ```
   app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
          // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
          // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

          spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

          // if (env.IsDevelopment())
          // {
          //     spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
          // }
          spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
      });
  ```

Comment: i see that after commenting out `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` it's up to me to run `npm build` before running `dotnet run`---thx for yr help!